# How to get odd column headers in Python?

Tags: python

I have data in file as shown below:

**odd_column.dat**

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7
1   1   1   1   2   2   2
2   2   4   2   5   5   3
3   3   9   3   10  10  4
4   4   16  4   17  17  5
5   5   25  5   26  26  6
6   6   36  6   37  37  7
7   7   49  7   50  50  8
8   8   64  8   65  65  9
9   9   81  9   82  82  10
```

And I am trying to get the odd column headers with this code (which does not work):

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
with open('odd_column.dat', "r") as data:
    while True:
        line = data.readline()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            break
    data_header = [i for i in line.strip().split('\t') if i]
odd_column_header = data_header[n for n in (1, 3, 5, 7)]
```

I have given only 7 total columns as an example. I would like to generalize it for thousands of columns, so that I get the headers of only the odd columns. How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Python slicing:

```
odd_column_header = data_header[0::2]
```

Comment: I think  it should be odd_column_header = data_header[0::2]

Comment: Yes, for your case. I've fixed.

Comment: In that case, just use `data_header[::2]`.